# CentOS: Fatal error: Call to undefined function exif_imagetype()

Tags: centos

On CentOS 7.1, I am greeted with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function exif_imagetype() in /some/path/to/a/php.file.php on line XXX
```

I can enable this in `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` on the following line:

```
870  ;extension=php_mbstring.dll
871  ;extension=php_exif.dll   ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
```

But the exif library is no where to be found on my system! `find / -name exif` does not find anything.

When I do `yum search`, I get the following packages:

```
libexif-devel.i686 : Files needed for libexif application development
libexif-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for libexif application development
libexif-doc.x86_64 : The EXIF Library API documentation
exiv2.x86_64 : Exif and Iptc metadata manipulation library
exiv2-libs.i686 : Exif and Iptc metadata manipulation library
exiv2-libs.x86_64 : Exif and Iptc metadata manipulation library
libexif.i686 : Library for extracting extra information from image files
libexif.x86_64 : Library for extracting extra information from image files
```

My question is, if I remove the `;`, rename the `php_exif.dll` and the `php_mbstring.dll`, to `php_mbstring.so`/`php_exif.so`, will I get rid of this error, or do I need to install one of the packages?

I am not familiar with this software!

Comment: Why is this voted for closing as off-topic and better suited to StackExchange when it's a simple package installation question?

Comment: I believe I was one of the "move to SO" voters. It looks to me like a question of how to configure php to enable a particular php function, not an error while trying to install a package. I thought a php programmer might have had better chances of seeing this than a system administrator, but I could be wrong!

Comment: '/usr/local/lib/php.ini' would never be a configuration file for a packaged php from a reputable repo. I suspect it is non-packaged software.

Answer (score 1):

If you run:

```
$ yum provides php-exif
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repo.bigstepcloud.com
 * epel: ftp.heanet.ie
 * extras: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
 * updates: centos.serverspace.co.uk
php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 : Common files for PHP
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Provides    : php-exif



php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 : Common files for PHP
Repo        : @base
Matched from:
Provides    : php-exif
```

you'll see that `php-exif` is part of the `php-common` package.  If you've installed `php` then `php-common` will be installed as a dependency.

Therefore you should be OK to remove the semicolon.

Comment: Running `yum provides php-exif` gives me the following message: `No matches found`. I did, `yum list installed php-common`, it then said: `Error: No matching Packages to list`, meaning php-common is not installed?

Comment: Are you sure you're on CentOS 7.1? I've just tried it on two machines and they both work.  What does `yum info php php-cli` show you? You're correct - the error message is telling you it's not installed.  Have you installed PHP by anther means, such as compiling it?

Comment: Will have to check that out tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy enough fix, I read and tried what was suggested and it did not work in my case.  All I did was simply this

```
Yum search exif
```

**RESULT**

```
*Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 
 * cpanel-plugins: 
 * base: centos4.zswap.net
 * epel: mirror.team-cymru.com
 * extras: centos4.zswap.net
 * updates: centos4.zswap.net

================================================ N/S matched: exif ================================================

libexif-devel.i686 : Files needed for libexif application development
libexif-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for libexif application development
libexif-doc.x86_64 : The EXIF Library API documentation
ea-php54-php-exif.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to work with image metadata
ea-php55-php-exif.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to work with image metadata
ea-php56-php-exif.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to work with image metadata
ea-php70-php-exif.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to work with image metadata
ea-php71-php-exif.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to work with image metadata
ea-php72-php-exif.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to work with image metadata
ea-php73-php-exif.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to work with image metadata
exiv2.x86_64 : Exif and Iptc metadata manipulation library
exiv2-libs.i686 : Exif and Iptc metadata manipulation library
exiv2-libs.x86_64 : Exif and Iptc metadata manipulation library
jhead.x86_64 : Tool for displaying EXIF data embedded in JPEG images
libexif.i686 : Library for extracting extra information from image files
libexif.x86_64 : Library for extracting extra information from image files
metadata-extractor2.noarch : Extracts EXIF, IPTC, XMP, ICC and other metadata from image files
nodejs-duplexify.noarch : Turn a writeable and readable stream into a single streams2 duplex stream
perl-Image-ExifTool.noarch : Utility for reading and writing image meta info
renrot.noarch : A program to rename and rotate files according to EXIF tags*
```

Next

```
yum install ea-php73-php-exif.x86_64 -y
```

That's that.

Comment: That isn't an answer.